# SWI-Prolog CGI cgi_get_form(Arguments) web hidden form

Tags: forms, list, web, prolog, swi-prolog

I have a problem passing the input type="hidden" form with the CGI library of SWI-Prolog. Specifically I do:

`<form id="frmCGIPrologIni" name="frmCGIPrologIni" method="post" action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/x.pl"> <p><input type="hidden" name="initial" value="ini" /> <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Start" /> </p></form>`

when the program x.pl calls `cgi_get_form(Arguments)` Arguments should be a list of Name(Value) terms, i,e: [Name, Value], so it should be [initial(ini)].

but when I use this it says: ERROR: =../2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

```
print_args([]).
print_args([F|T]) :- % with Arguments
    F =.. [Name, Value], % and should continue doing things
```

I've tried to print it manually with write(Arguments) and what I get is: `_L160`, and printing the first element is: `_G472` and write_canonical(Arguments) returns: `'.'(_,_)`

I've tried also using the method="get" just for checking it and it prints the URI correctly `http://localhost/cgi-bin/x.pl?initial=ini` so I guess is not a problem of submitting but of handling with cgi_get_form(Arguments).

The first time 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/x.pl' runs I do:

```
cgi_get_form(Arguments),

(Arguments = []) ->
(
format('<p>Print this as the index.</p>~n', []),
) ; true, % and it works well because there are no Arguments the first time

write('<p>'), write(Arguments), write('</p>'), nl, % and print other things
```

The problem is the second time. This time calling the same program there are Arguments so it doesn't print the message, up to here everything is fine. Then goes through true and continues. That's when I try to write(Arguments) with the results explained before (`_L160`). And the results should be the data passed by the form.

any thoughts on what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
print_args([F|T]) :- % with Arguments
    F =.. [Name | Value], % and should continue doing things
```